# Angular (4): disable the whole form (group) instead of each input separately?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to disable the whole form (group) in angular instead of doing it for every input separately?

Something like `<input [disabled]="formNotValid"/>` but for a `<form>` or a `<div ngModelGroup..>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If You use ReactiveForms just write

```
form: formGroup;

this.form.disable();
```

In case of ngForm you can write like this' created [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IqUQz2eOQd72CZjD4r2c?p=preview)

```
 <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
  <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel">
  <input name="last" ngModel>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<button (click)="disable(f)">Disable form</button>



 disable(f) {
    f.form.disable()
  }
```

Comment: I use template driven forms in this case.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a solution that automatically disables all form-elements when the submit-button is clicked.**

This solution applies to *template-driven* forms.

**HTML:**

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit( myForm )">

    <input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="model.title" #title="ngModel">

    <button type="submit">

        <span *ngIf="!imyForm.disabled">
            Submit Form
        <span>

        <span *ngIf="myForm.disabled">
            Submitted
        <span>

    </button>

</form>
```

**TS:**

```
public onFormSubmit( form: any): void {
    form.form.disable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be considered hack-y, but you could use ngClass and css to apply a class that turns off pointer events for all inputs inside a container when conditions are met.

```
.disable-inputs {
  pointer-events: none;
}

<form [ngClass]="{'disable-inputs':[true/false condition]}">
   // input elements
</form>
```